# Consumir servicio rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, http

Estoy tratando de consumir un servicio rest pero al momento de hacerlo me envía un error.

Dejo abajo el código que estoy ocupando.

```
import http.client


metadatos = {a:1, b:2, c:3}


conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("10.133.xxx.xxx")
        conn.request("PUT", "/rest", metadatos)
        resp = conn.getresponse()
        print(resp.status, resp.reason)
```

Si hace la conexión pero al momento de hacer el PUT es donde me aparece el error

El error que me envía es el siguiente

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1591, in 
>       globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1018, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2017.1.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "C:/Users/mxe01508121A/PycharmProjects/PublicadorFirmaAutografaDigital/PublicadorFAD.py",
>   line 73, in 
>       conn.request("PUT", "/rest", metadatos)   File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1239, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
>   "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1285, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1234, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
>   "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1064, in _send_output
>       + b'\r\n' TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Espero me puedan ayudar.

saludos!

Comment: Elimina `http://` de la direccion y prueba a ver que obtienes.

Comment: aparece el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

La parte más informativa es `Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed` y básicamente te está informando que no puede resolver la dirección configurada en `hcpConn2`, los motivos pueden ser múltiples:

- La dirección no existe o está mal configurada (eventualmente probar por IP)
- El puerto está cerrado
- Usas un proxy y no esta funcionando
- No tienes conexión a internet
- etc. etc.

Comment: Hice un cambio en el código y ahora el error que me aparece es el que esta arriba

Comment: @Memo, ahora respuesta y pregunta no tienen nada que ver, te sugiero que en estos casos abras siempre otra pregunta. En principio te comento que `metadatos = {a:1, b:2, c:3}` esta mal definido, debiera ser algo así: `metadatos = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}`, revisalo y cualquier cosa edito mi respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenté en un principio, antes de la edición de la pregunta, no puedes incluir el prefijo del protocolo en la dirección. Al usar `http.client.HTTPConnection` ya se sobreentiende que el protocolo es `http`. Por lo tanto no debe usarse `"http://10.133.xxx.xxx/..."` sino `"10.133.xxx.xxx/..."`.

En cuanto al error actual, primero el diccionario no es válido, en todo caso debería ser algo como: `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`, segundo, no puedes pasar alegremente un objeto map (un diccionario) al argumento `body` de `http.client.HTTPConnection.request`.

No sabemos nada de como tratas ese `PUT` en el servidor, lo cual no facilita las cosas. No obstante, puedes usar [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) para convertir el diccionario en una cadena “url-encoded”:

```
import http.client
import urllib.parse


metadatos = urllib.parse.urlencode({"a":1, "b":2, "c":3})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Accept": "text/plain"}

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8080)
conn.request("PUT", "/rest", metadatos,  headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.status, resp.reason)
```

O usar un JSON:

```
import http.client
import json


metadatos = json.dumps({"a":1, "b":2, "c":3})
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",
           'Accept': "application/json"}

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8080)
conn.request("PUT", "/rest", metadatos,  headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.status, resp.reason)
```

> **Nota 1:** cambia el host y el puerto, los códigos son solo a modo de ejemplo simplificado.Sería de gran ayuda saber como tratas esa petición en el servidor y como parseas los datos para poder ayudarte mejor.

---

> **Nota 2:** Te recomiendo usar la magnífica biblioteca [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) si vas a trabajar con esto asiduamente. `http.client`/`http.server` son módulos de bajo nivel y más engorrosos de usar, aunque nada impide hacerlo, por supuesto.